# How to use WHERE BETWEEN and GROUP BY at same time

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

How do I use **where between** and **group by** in same query

```
  SELECT `sales-store-id`,
  (SUM (`gen-acute-sales-after-returns`) + SUM(`gen- chronic-sales-after-returns`)) 
   AS `totalGenericSales` ,
  (SUM (`eth-acute-sales- after-returns`) + SUM(`eth-chronic-sales-after-returns`) + SUM(`others-sales- 
after-returns`))
 AS `totalEthicalSales` 
 FROM `sales` GROUP BY `sales-store-id` 
WHERE `date-s` BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2018-10-01'
```

this is giving SQL error so i tried **AND** in place of **WHERE**  but that is also not grouping results properly it is only giving 2 results with same id

```
   SELECT `sales-store-id`,
      (SUM (`gen-acute-sales-after-returns`) + SUM(`gen- chronic-sales-after-returns`)) 
       AS `totalGenericSales` ,
      (SUM (`eth-acute-sales- after-returns`) + SUM(`eth-chronic-sales-after-returns`) + SUM(`others-sales- 
    after-returns`))
     AS `totalEthicalSales` 
     FROM `sales` GROUP BY `sales-store-id` 
    AND `date-s` BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2018-10-01'
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: GROUP BY should be last.

Comment: Group by should always go after conditions

Comment: Select -> from -> Join -> Where -> Group BY -> Having -> Order -> Limit

Comment: We are geussing here provide example data and expected results..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause should appear before the `GROUP BY` clause in the SQL statement.

The order of clauses defined by the SQL language is:

- SELECT
- FROM
- JOIN
- WHERE
- GROUP BY
- HAVING
- ORDER BY
- LIMIT (MySQL Extension)

Comment: Not "typically".  That is the ordering defined by the SQL language.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you - I have corrected the terminology in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can not use **where** clause after **group by**.
Use this query

```
SELECT `sales-store-id`,
  (SUM (`gen-acute-sales-after-returns`) + SUM(`gen- chronic-sales-after-returns`)) 
   AS `totalGenericSales` ,
  (SUM (`eth-acute-sales- after-returns`) + SUM(`eth-chronic-sales-after-returns`) + SUM(`others-sales- 
after-returns`))
 AS `totalEthicalSales` 
 FROM `sales`
```

where `date-s` BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2018-10-01'
GROUP BY `sales-store-id`

Comment: Why? HAVING and WHERE work different.. Based on the non existing example data or expected results you can't say if the topicstarter needs a WHERE filter or the GROUP BY filter with HAVING..

Answer (score 1):

There is a hierarchical order in which these keywords should written which is as follows:

`SELECT`, `FROM`, `JOIN`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, `ORDER BY`

```
 SELECT `sales-store-id`,
        (SUM (`gen-acute-sales-after-returns`) + SUM(`gen- chronic-sales-after-returns`)) 
     AS `totalGenericSales` ,
        (SUM (`eth-acute-sales- after-returns`) + SUM(`eth-chronic-sales-after-returns`) 
       + SUM(`others-sales-after-returns`)) 
     AS `totalEthicalSales`
   FROM `sales`
  WHERE `date-s` BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2018-10-01'
  GROUP BY `sales-store-id`;
```